# Trying endless runner game in unity 3d with 5Lane at place of 3Lane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I m trying to edit however, the condition under the if else loops are not executing the task. In this code lanedistance is constant float variable with value 2.0f. As describe earlier it is 5lane endless runner so desired lane is considered as int variable with value 2 for middle (Ext. Left = 0, Left = 1, Middle = 2, Right = 3, Ext. Right = 4)               -----------------

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        MoveLane(false);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        MoveLane(true);

    Vector3 targetposition = transform.position.z * Vector3.forward;
    if (desiredLane == 0)
    {   
        targetposition += Vector3.left * laneDistance; 
    }

    else if (desiredLane == 1)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {   //Debug.Log("1i condition");
            MoveLane(true);
            targetposition += Vector3.left * laneDistance;
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {   
            //Debug.Log("1e condition");
            MoveLane(false);
            targetposition += Vector3.right * laneDistance;
        }
    }

    else if (desiredLane == 3)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {   
            //Debug.Log("3i condition");
            MoveLane(true);
            targetposition += Vector3.left * laneDistance;
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {   //Debug.Log("3e condition");
            MoveLane(true);
            targetposition += Vector3.right * laneDistance;
        }
    }

    else if (desiredLane == 4)//                                                    ---------------------- 
        targetposition += Vector3.right * laneDistance;





    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = (targetposition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;
    moveVector.y = -0.1f;
    moveVector.z = speed;

    controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void MoveLane(bool goingRight)
{
    desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 5 : -1;//                                                                 ------------------
    desiredLane = Mathf.Clamp(desiredLane, 0, 4);//                                                         ------------------
    Debug.Log("Value is: "+desiredLane);
}
```

}

Comment: I would check this line: `desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 5 : -1;//  `. I do not understand very well you lane change logic, I would expect the values to change by 1 or 2 units, not 5

Comment: @rustyBucketBay well I tried that last night... It doesn't make an impact.

Comment: what is it that you tried? If the else statement is not being executed, is that the condition for the else is not being met. You just need to [debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code with breakpoints and figure out why

Comment: I tried.. else statement in both the conditions are not working and if I remove (desiredLane == 1) and else if (desiredLane == 3) conditions player can easily work in 3lanes...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code can be simplified a lot.

Also why would you handle the first two `GetKeyDown` statements always without any check at all? And what happened to the case where `desiredLane == 2`?

And why do you use

```
desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 5 : -1
```

it should probably rather be

```
desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1
```

I'd say you rather want to do something like

```
// Configure these two vis the Inspector!
public float sidewardsSpeed;
public float forwardSpeed;

// Not necessary but this way you can give your checks handy names
private bool CanMoveLeft => desiredLane > 0;
private bool CanMoveRight => desiredLane < 4;

float targetPositionX;

void Start()
{
    targetPositionX = transform.position.x;
}

void Update()
{
    // This is for the sidewards movement
    // It's enough to simply check the value of your index ONCE instead of 
    // covering each possible case ;)
    if (CanMoveLeft && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        MoveLane(false);
    else if (CanMoveRight && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        MoveLane(true);

    // Finally calculate a smoothed movement on the individual axes
    var currentPosition = transform.position;
    var deltaX = targetPositionX - currentPosition.x;
    var x = Mathf.Min(deltaX, Mathf.Sign(deltaX) * sidewardsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    var y = -0.1f * Time.deltaTime;
    var z = forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // And then apply both movements 
    controller.Move(new Vector3(x, y, z));
}    

private void MoveLane(bool goingRight)
{
    var direction = goingRight ? 1 : -1;
    desiredLane += direction; 
    desiredLane = Mathf.Clamp(desiredLane, 0, 4);                         
    Debug.Log("Value is: "+desiredLane);
 
    // Also directly calculate the target X position     
    targetPositionX = (desiredLane - 2) * laneDistance;
}
```